# Debugging Undefined Offset in CakePhp

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I am receiving the following error:

> Notice (8): Undefined offset: 47
>   [APP/Template\CoursesEnrolled\view.ctp, line 75]

I have tried debugging the line but I'm stuck with what to do.

My view.ctp looks like this:

```
$modulesEnrolled = Cake\Utility\Hash::combine($coursesEnrolled->courses_enrolled_modules,
'{n}.course_module_id','{n}');
// debug($modulesEnrolled);

$allModulesCompleted = true;

if (!empty($coursesEnrolled->course->course_modules)): ?>
    <div class="">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="toggletable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><?= __('Title') ?></th>
                <th><?= __('Type') ?></th>
                <th class="actions"><?= __('Actions') ?></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($coursesEnrolled->course->course_modules as $courseModules): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?= h($courseModules->title) ?></td>
                <td><?= h($courseModules->type) ?></td>
                <td class="actions">
                <?php 
                    if($allModulesCompleted && $modulesEnrolled[$courseModules->id]['status'] == 'Pending') { //this is line 75
                        $allModulesCompleted = false;
                    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is, one of your arrays doesn't start at 0.

The `$courseModules->id` doesn't match the any key in the `$modulesEnrolled` array.

I would try either incrementing or decrementing by 1, maybe try the following:

```
$IDHere = (int)$courseModules->id - 1;
if($allModulesCompleted && $modulesEnrolled[$IDHere]['status'] == 'Pending') { //this is line 75
     $allModulesCompleted = false;
}
```

Comment: Sorry that didn't work :( I tried incrementing and decrementing and neither worked.